# Grouped cell in first row of DT datatable Excel download

Tags: r, shiny, dt

when using the button extension in DT datatables to download the table in Excel, per default the first row in the downloaded Excel is a grouped cell, indicating the source of the download:

[image]

Question: Is there a way/option to avoid this first row to be outputted?

Comment: In DataTables this is done by setting the [`title` export option](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportInfo()) to `null`: `title: null`. I am not sure how that translates to a DT implementation - hence this is only a comment. I think it also works if you set the title to an empty string: `title: ""`.

Comment: Thanks @andrewJames! Unfortunately, this does not seem to work in DT ... `code` DT::datatable(
  data = mtcars,
  extensions = 'Buttons',
  options = list(
    title = NULL,
    dom = 'tB',
    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel')
  ),
  class = "display"
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment in the question, you have this code:

```
DT::datatable( 
  data = mtcars, 
  extensions = 'Buttons', 
  options = list( 
    title = NULL, 
    dom = 'tB', 
    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel') 
  ), 
  class = "display" 
)
```

However, with this approach, you have provided `title = NULL` as a DataTable option - outside of the Buttons options.

So, instead you need to use this option as a Buttons option - specifically as an extension (`extend = 'excel'`) for the Excel button.

Here is my version of this, but using a simple R script, rather than Shiny.

```
library(DT)
iris2 = head(iris, 20)
datatable(
  iris2,
  extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    
    buttons = 
      list('copy', 'csv', list(
        extend = 'excel',
        filename = 'test123',
        title = NULL
      ))
    
  )
)
```

This uses the Buttons `extend` option  to customize the Excel button - including the `title = NULL` option.

This gives the following output:

[image]

Notes:

(1) I am not very familiar with configuring DataTables options in R, so there may be a more standard approach than the one I have used here.

(2) This approach should work in a Shiny example - although I have not tested that.

Comment: It works in a Shiny example, too! Awesome, thanks!